# Access Web App - Macro to populate field based on another field

Tags: ms-access, office365, ms-access-web-app, ms-access-data-macro

I'm building my first Access Web App using Access 2016.  I'm looking for guidance on how to populate two fields based on the value selected in another.  Here's what I have.  The source data is:

```
[Producers].[Company]
[Producers].[Phone]
[Producers].[Email]
```

Referencing this data is:

```
[GC Insurance].[Producers] - lookup field to [Producers].[Company]
[GC Insurance].[ProducerPhone]
[GC Insurance].[ProducerEmail]
```

I would like for the values in [GC Insurance].[ProducerPhone] and [GC Insurance].[ProducerEmail] to auto populate based on the value selected in [GC Insurance].[Producers].

Any help would surely be appreciated!

Thank you,

Stacey

Comment: You shouldn't. AWA will be phased out quite soon: [We no longer recommend Access Services for new apps](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-Retirement-Blog/Updating-the-Access-Services-in-SharePoint-Roadmap/ba-p/57148)

Comment: This requires code. Why do you want to duplicate data? Why not just save the ID from Producers and then build query that joins tables?